# How to compare similar text files and output duplicates?

Tags: python, linux, compare

I'm looking to compare two `txt` files that are similar but prioritize one of them which may contain more data at the end.

For example:

file1.txt

```
  userID:userBalance:userType:userCountry
  userID1:userBalance1:userType1:userCountry
  userID2:userBalance2:userType2:userCountry
  userID3:userBalanc3:userType3:userCountry
```

file2.txt

```
  userID:userBalance
  userID1:userBalance1
  userID2:userBalance2
```

output.txt

```
  userID:userBalance:userType:userCountry
  userID1:userBalance1:userType1:userCountry
  userID2:userBalance1:userType2:userCountry
```

I would like the output to print lines from file1 that contain similar text from file2.

I've tried several methods already which have only worked if each line is the same, there couldn't be additional string even though the first 2 parts are the same like in the example above.

From what I've found I would need some way to compare only the initial string from each line separated by " : " and output the line from file1 if its found in file2.

Comment: Check out the *nix `join` utility ; [Here's a Tutorial](https://shapeshed.com/unix-join/) . Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

With python you can check if a string is include in another one just using the *in* keyword:

```
str2 in str1
```

So you can do something like this:

```
lines1 = list()
lines2 = list()

with open('file1.txt', 'r') as f1:
    for l1 in f1:
        lines1.append(l1.strip())

with open('file2.txt', 'r') as f2:
    for l2 in f2:
        lines2.append(l2.strip())

with open('output.txt', 'w') as out:
    for elt in [l1 for l2 in lines2 for l1 in lines1 if l2 in l1]:
        out.write('{}\n'.format(elt))
```

The most important part is:

```
[l1 for l2 in lines2 for l1 in lines1 if l2 in l1]
```

It means that you want to create a new list of **l1** (lines of text from your file1.txt) if any **l2** (lines of text from your file2.txt) is include in this **l1**

Comment: This merged the two together - therefor adding the file2 data that was in file1 ontop of the output additionally with all of file1's data. Needed to only output exact lines from file1 that were in file2

Comment: @GGNoPotato You must have implemented this solution incorrectly, or your real data is significantly different.  The code produced by Yannick, correctly creates `ouput.text`, from the test data, as specified in your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

My first idea is use `.split(":")` and put each split string into an array for each line, then for the example you gave, only compare the first two indeces of the lists. Pseudocode could look like this for each line of the file:

```
stringArray = fullStringFromFile1.split(":")
stringArray2 = fullStringFromFile2.split(":")
for i in range(len(smallestStringArray)):
    if stringArray[i] == stringArray2[i]:
         duplicateStringList.append(stringArray[i])
```

Hope this helps point you in the right direction